# How to add a hyperlink to AutoGeneratedEdit Button in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view which gives project info.I have added edit button.

My grid view looks something like this

```
              **ProjectID**     **ProjectName**    **Action**
      edit       231                  abc                xyz
      edit       1223                 pqr                asj
      edit       325                  asgf               wrgag
```

Now When i click on edit it should point to another page.
How to Set NavigateUrl for that AutogeneratedEdit

Comment: have you done any coding at all.. for example where is the button Click event ..please show the code.. also what do you mean by auto generated Edit..? you want to look at `Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer` please be more specific in what you are looking for

Comment: My apologizes its not a button its a link present in gridview

Comment: AutogeneratedEdit = true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't auto generate the edit.  Put a field in the grid view declaration for it.  In the field, put an anchor tag runat server. OnRowCreated, find the anchor control and set the href to your URL.  I have done it that way several times. I can provide sample code if needed.

UPDATE: Sample Code Below

In ASPX/ASCX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" OnRowCreated="RowCreated">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <a ID="lnkDelete" runat="server">Action</a>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In Codebehind:

```
protected void RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        HtmlAnchor deleteButton = (HtmlAnchor)e.Row.FindControl("lnkDelete");

        //Do your stuff with that delete button
    }
}
```

Comment: Will do, but can't until tomorrow.

Comment: Updated to include sample code.  Mark as answer if this works for you.  Good Luck!

Comment: why not to put a `LinkButton` and handle the `RowCommand` event?

Comment: Better question is why do that. You still need to handle row created to add the command argument and the row command would be an extra post back just to give a Response.Redirect.  If you do it this way you avoid the post back because the anchor will be handled client side.